# MySQL Update error while updating table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have table in MySQL with years as column names like 1960, 1961, 1962... etc. Records are being inserted successfully. When I try to update table with query

```
UPDATE table1 SET 1960=0.0 WHERE id = 'abc'
```

it gives:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your 
MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '1960=0.0 WHERE id='abc' at line 1
```

Is it due to columns names as numbers or something else is wrong?

Comment: Thats a **very** bad choice of naming columns. Anyway, try to surround 1960 with a pair of backtick operator..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to escape your column names by using the backtick character. The following manual page is [somewhat dense but informative](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/identifiers.html)

Try...

```
UPDATE table1 SET `1960`=0.0 WHERE id = 'abc'
```

Answer (score 3):

try this:

```
UPDATE table1 SET `1960`='0.0' WHERE id = 'abc'
```

... added backticks to column name and single quotes around value (not really required for the value, but I always do it)

Answer (score 3):

escape your column name with backticks

```
UPDATE table1 SET `1960` = 0.0 WHERE id = 'abc'
```

That has to be done if your column name is a [reserved keyword](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html) in MySQL or a number.